# Getting errors while trying to get SQL Server Agent to work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent

I am trying to get SQL Server Agent on an instance of 2014 and an instance of 2016 to run. Currently both of them start up but then immediately stop with the message: The SQL Server Agent (VERSION16) service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.

I read on other issues that this is typically due to a permission issue. I checked the event viewer but all I saw was Event ID 101: SQLServerAgent service successfully started. followed by Event ID 102: SQLServerAgent service successfully stopped.

In order to rule out a permissions issue I went into SQL Server Configuration Manager running as an admin, went to the agent properties and switched Log on to the Built-in account: Local System. When I click OK I am getting the following error: The process terminated unexpectedly. [0x8007042b].

I am unsure where to go from here. I need this agent up as there are several nightly jobs that need to be run on a production database running on this instance. One of these is a nightly backup that is currently never executing. I am logged into the system as a user that is both a local and domain admin so there shouldn't be any permission issue here, please let me know if you can think of anything else I can try to get this working.

Here is the error log:

> 2017-08-31 15:25:10 - ? [100] Microsoft SQLServerAgent version 13.0.4001.0 (X64 unicode retail build) : Process ID 19680
>   2017-08-31 15:25:10 - ? [495] The SQL Server Agent startup service account is NE-REVAL\NEREVAL$.
>   2017-08-31 15:25:11 - ? [393] Waiting for SQL Server to recover database 'msdb'...
>   2017-08-31 15:25:11 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 229, The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (DisableAgentXPs)
>   2017-08-31 15:25:11 - ! [000] The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 229)
>   2017-08-31 15:25:11 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 229, The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (DisableAgentXPs)
>   2017-08-31 15:25:11 - ! [000] The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 229)
>   2017-08-31 15:25:11 - ? [098] SQLServerAgent terminated (normally)

Comment: it seems you are using express version which doesn't have sql agent

Comment: Check SQL Server Agent from Windows Services, is it set to startup automatically? Does it allow you to start the service from there? If not what is the error?

Comment: I am using the following version: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 Essentials 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )

Comment: Yes it is set to start automatically and when I start it from Windows Services I get the message: The SQL Server Agent (VERSION16) service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.

Comment: And what does the error log for the agent say? And can we ignore the 2014 instance for now since you did not provide any specific information about it?

Comment: Yes the 2014 instance can be ignored for now as there are no current production databases on it and I am assuming the issue is similar since I am having the same error messages. How do I get to the agent log as there is nothing being logged in the Event Viewer other then successful start followed by successful stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it stop working, or is this a new installation?

Try changing the SQL Server Agent to use the same account that SQL Server is using.

If that doesn't work, create a new local user (like "mssqlsvc2014" or "mssqlsvc2016") and use the SQL Server Configuration Manager to have the SQL Server Agent use that user.

Comment: This is the first time I have attempted to get the agent running on this install. The Agents on my 2000, 2008, and 2012 instances all run, my 2014 instance is having the same error.

I have tried to change the user in SQL Server Configuration Manager but get the following error no matter which user I try: The process terminated unexpectedly. [0x8007042b]

Comment: Ended up changing the account in Microsoft Services instead of Configuration Manager to the domain admin which is also a SQL sysadmin. This has fixed the issue.